# Move multiple nested files up until they are only 1 directory deep

Tags: linux, bash, find, mv

I have multiple files in multiple directories some buried under subdirectories. I want to be able to move all files until they are only 1 directory deep.

for example:

```
/home/folder/subfolder/file1.txt
/home/folder2/file2.txt
/home/folder3/subfolder/subfolder/subfolder/file3.txt
```

becomes:

```
/home/folder/file1.txt
/home/folder2/file2.txt
/home/folder3/file3.txt
```

I found that I can use

```
find ./*/ -type f
```

to locate all the files. But I'm not sure how to move them so that they are only 1 directory deep.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in the form of a bash script

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS='
'
for i in $(find ./*/ -mindepth 2 -type f); do
    mv -- "${i}" "${i%/*/*}"
done
```